List all custom shortcuts
After working with IntelliJ for a while I have managed to create some useful keyboard-shortcuts (I think). But unfortunately I can't remember all the shortcuts I have set up, so some of them was probably not that useful.
Q1: Is there a way to list all the custom shortcuts that I have created?
Q2: Is there a way to restore all shortcuts to the defaults and by that also removing all the custom ones?

File -> Settings  and select Keymap in the tree. You should see with a different color (eg light blue) all the groups (folders) with "changes" as well as the custom keymaps when you expand them. Above, you have a dropdown with your current scheme (eg "Windows copy" if you have changes and did not give it a custom name), which you can delete (cog icon to the right of it) a/o select a predefined one.
